# JAXWS: Why would one generate the client code within maven through jaxws-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws

I was always using wsimport tool to generate client classes from a WSDL file. Then I was including them into a project's source tree and checking them into the version control system. But recently I learnt that there is a plugin for maven called jaxws-maven-plugin that can generate the client classes as a build step (mvn clean jaxws:wsimport).

Although it is not clear for me what are the real benefits of using this plugin except no need to checking the WS client classes into source control. Still if someone wants to work on the project, he has to checkout the code, then run mvn jaxws:wsimport and only then can start working (otherwise an IDE will show errors). So what are the real benefits and when one should use the plugin instead of checking in the client code into VCS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execution of maven plugins can be triggered automatically in a build step, e.g. there is dedicated a "generate sources" phase in the maven build cycle, right before compilation of the project. Therefore a developer will not have to remember to generate it manually, bringing you closer to the ideal one-click full build.

The advantage is, that you can exclude the generated classes from the VCS, as they can be regenerated on demand. The problem with generated code in VCS is, that a change in the WSDL file will trigger changes in the generated code (obviously). But as you are working contract first, only the changes in the WSDL file are relevant. Excluding the generated code from the VCS will hide redundant changes in it from the VCS commit log. Your VCS repository is smaller and the commit logs cleaner.

*edit aimed at comment*:
Imho there are two distinct views on that scenario:

1) Compatibility of client classes to service interface.

I am not sure, if client classes are able to communicate with a WS, if they are generated from an older wsdl. I think it **may** work, if the changes are limited to additional methods and do not touch existing definitions. Nonetheless, if the client code is always regenerated on a build, this is a non-issue, as the client code is in sync with the wsdl automatically.

2) Compatibility of implementation to client classes.

If the generated client classes change, due to a modified wsdl, this can break code, which uses the client classes. But if there are only methods added to a wsdl and existing methods are left as they are, the regenerated client classes should consequently be backwards compatible with existing code. In your example: If your code only uses A(), and the "new" client classes now offer B() **in addition** to A(), your code should still work.

In summary; excluding generated client code from the VCS and instead generating it on demand as part of the build process should in my opinion not break existing, functional code, if the WSDL evolution is backwards compatible. If the WSDL changes are not backwards compatible, errors will occur at compile time. But these are inevitable - using outdated client classes from the VCS may actually hide these errors until you try to execute the application.

Comment: So lets say a wsdl defines a method A() which I want to use. I generate client classes, develope the code and then check-in everything to a VCS. In the meantime the wsdl changes and there is a new method added B(). Then I would have to generate a new client classes and check them in. Otherwise the code wouldn't work, even if I use only A()?